# Replace load event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a loader for the *data loading section*. but, I already have a loader for *before loading full website data*.

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
  // Animate loader off screen
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
});`
```

And now I set this, to load the data section.

```
const npreloader = document.querySelector('.npreloader');
const fadeEffect = setInterval(() => {
  // if we don't set opacity 1 in CSS, then   
  // it will be equal to "", that's why we   
  // check it
  if (!npreloader.style.opacity) {
    npreloader.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  if (npreloader.style.opacity > 0) {
    npreloader.style.opacity -= 0.1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(fadeEffect);
  }
}, 500);
window.addEventListener('load', ()=> fadeEffect);
```

Can I replace the event keyword "load" with any event? Because it overrides each other.

Comment: You can use any custom event, eg `$(window).on("data_loading", ...` - the question is how are you going to *raise* (/trigger) that event?   When the window loads, the browser raises the `load` event which you listen to.  You can't rename that as it's raised by the browser.  If you're firing off your own events, then name them whatever you want.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*[they] override each other*" - you can add any number of event listeners and they will *all* fire.

Comment: You do have an issue in that `const fadeEffect = setInterval(() => .., n);` will set fadeEffect to the setInterval interval ID and **start the interval immediately** (eg https://jsfiddle.net/pcf5st2d/) - your code does not define a function that can be called on load (so is running immediately).  If it was a function then you would need `.addEventListener('load', ()=> fadeEffect())` - try debugging `fadeEffect` - add a a console.log inside the setInterval.  This might be the cause of your confusion.